# How to write a function with an interactive choice of the value of the argument?

Tags: completion, interactive, menus

How to write a function in Emacs Lisp that interactively would give the opportunity to choose one of the options?

```
Choose your animal: Cow Rabbit Dog
```

You have to press `1` to select `Cow`, `2` to select `Rabbit` and `3` to select `Dog`

Comment: This looks like a dup. Perhaps someone can locate the duplicate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function you are looking for is `read-char-choice`.
I cite the corresponding documentation:

> (read-char-choice PROMPT CHARS &optional INHIBIT-KEYBOARD-QUIT)
>
> Read and return one of CHARS, prompting for PROMPT.
>   Any input that is not one of CHARS is ignored.
>
> If optional argument INHIBIT-KEYBOARD-QUIT is non-nil, ignore
>   keyboard-quit events while waiting for a valid input.

A usage example:

```el
(defvar valeriy-alist '((?1 "Cow" (lambda () (message "I am a cow") 'cow))
            (?2 "Rabbit" (lambda () (message "I am a lion") 'lion))
            (?3 "Dog" (lambda () (message "I am a wolf") 'wolf)))
  "List that associates number letters to descriptions and actions.")

(defun valeriy-choose ()
  "Lets the user choose the animal and takes the corresponding action.
Returns whatever the action returns."
  (interactive)
  (let ((choice (read-char-choice (mapconcat (lambda (item) (format "%c: %s" (car item) (cadr item))) valeriy-alist "; ")
                  (mapcar #'car valeriy-alist))))
    (funcall (nth 2 (assoc choice valeriy-alist)))))
```

Comment: Awesome! This is exactly what I wanted to get

Answer (score 8):

```el
(defun foo (choice)
  "..."
  (interactive
   (list (completing-read "Choose: "
                          '(("1" . "Cow") ("2" . "Rabbit") ("3" . "Dog")) nil t)))
  (message "You chose `%s'" choice)
  choice)
```

Or if you want to let the input be the first letter (or another prefix):

```el
(defun foo (choice)
  "..."
  (interactive
   (let ((completion-ignore-case  t))
     (list (completing-read "Choose: " '("Cow" "Rabbit" "Dog") nil t))))
  (message "You chose `%s'" choice)
  choice)
```