# Changing highlighting of headings interactively

Tags: highlighting, outline

I would like to have the ability to interactively change the highlighting settings using a single function (named `outline-activate`).  How can I adapt it for the task described?

```
(defun outline-activate ()
  "Activates 'outline-minor-mode' on current buffer."

  ;; Controls how outlines are highlighted

  ;; Outline Typefaces applied only if Major-Mode.
  (setq outline-minor-mode-highlight t)

  ;; Outline Typefaces appended to Major-Mode Settings.
  (setq outline-minor-mode-highlight 'append)

  ;; Outline Typefaces overrid Major-Mode Settings.
  (setq outline-minor-mode-highlight 'override)

  (outline-minor-mode 1)
  (outline-hide-body))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can prompt the user for the highlight type, I think [this post](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/32248/how-to-write-a-function-with-an-interactive-choice-of-the-value-of-the-argument) will help you.

Comment: Although I could use `(list (completing-read "Outline-Highlight: " '("t" "Append" "Override")  nil t))`, the variable `outline-minor-mode-highlight` takes symbols.

Comment: You can parse the user's choice using a `cond` statement and `string-equal` to properly set `outline-minor-mode-highlight`. @Pampalula

Comment: Could `completing-read` pass the symbol directly so there is just one call `(setq outline-minor-mode-highlight csym)` ?

Comment: I quickly tried it before writing my first comment and I did not manage to direclty get a symbol from `completing-read` to give to `outline-minor-mode-highlight`. But there might be a way to do it. As you seem to begin with Emacs-lisp (just like me), I think you are fine with a `cond`. You will be able to improve `outline-activate` later.

Comment: @Pampalula if this worked for you, please mark the answer as accepted.